# Google Photos return inverse order photos when asking for EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, android-gallery, google-photos

I am asking for images from a gallery app with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

I am reading the results like this:

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
Uri[] uris = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < uris.length; i++) {
  uris[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
}
```

I noticed that when I use Google Photos as the gallery, the results come back in a reverse order to that I have selected in Google Photos' ui.

Is that intentional, consistent or documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ACTION_PICK` is the wrong `Intent` action. If you read [the documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), that is for picking content from a specific collection; MIME type is not one of the documented input values. [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) is for picking content based on a MIME type.

Second, note that [`EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is for use with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE). Hence, few `ACTION_PICK` implementations will honor that extra.

Third, there is no requirement for the `Uri` values returned from an `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` request to be in any particular order. There are thousands of possible apps that will respond to your request, and they can send you the results in whatever order they wish. In particular, [the documentation for `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE) does not address order.

If order matters in your app, build your own UI to confirm the order. Offer a convenient one-click "reverse" option, in addition to perhaps drag-and-drop to allow for arbitrary changes. After all, the user may not realize, during the content selection, that order matters, and so even the order in which the user chose the content is not the user's actual desired order.

Comment: Thank you so much!
After switching to GET_CONTENT, my Nexus 4 opens a new kind of screen (not a "choose gallery") with a list of galleries + list of folders + apps like Google Drive. 
Selecting multiple photos in the "native" folders, acts exactly as I expected order-wise. 
I think Google-Photos' behaviour sucks - they show the images in some order, so I'd expect them to return it to the caller in the same order.